# What are all the dependencies of firebase-crash?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

When I add firebase-crash in my project I have the following error :

```
NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnl$1
```

more precisely this is the error I have :

```
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902): Firebase API initialization failure.
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1737)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1712)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6453)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6048)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5988)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:211)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1766)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnl$1
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnl.<init>(Unknown Source)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.<init>(Unknown Source)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source)
05-06 13:13:31.800: A/FirebaseApp(11902):   ... 22 more
```

So it seems I might have missed some library in my app. But how to find out? I am not using `Android Studio`, I am using `Delphi`.

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: i don't have any build gradle under delphi, under delphi i just include in my project the file 'firebase-crash.jar' ... but i think i miss some other jar :(

Comment: Try to add the "core" dependency com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4

Comment: @PavelPoley thanks, i try but firebase-core-10.2.4.aar is empty :( so maybe it's in other package now ?

Comment: ok, i see it's seam i need to include firebase-analytics in my project ...

Comment: You can see the full dependency tree for any android project by running `./gradlew androidDependencies`

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks this is very usefull! is their anyway to run gradlew only on a dedicated jar instead of an android studio project (because i m not under android studio)

Comment: That task is dependent on knowing your project structure, as defined by your build.grade.  Individual jars don't have any knowledge of how they were built, so you can't really run the same thing against one particular jar.